# Multiple object in one LiveData

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-room, android-livedata

I have this Entity:

```
@Entity
public class CartItem {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private long id;
    private long itemId;
    private long serviceId;
    private String observation;
    @Ignore
    private Service service;
    @Ignore
    private Item item;
}
```

As you can see it's composed by others objects, in that case, `Service` and `Item`.

In the fragment I'm implementing the LiveData this way:

```
CartItemViewModel model = CartItemViewModel.create(getActivity());
model.getLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<CartItem>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<CartItem> cartItems) {

}
```

It's working, `onChange` method is being called as expected.

And this is my ViewModel in kotlin:

```
class CartItemViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val liveData: LiveData<List<CartItem>> = MainApplication.getInstance().cartItemDao.liveData

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun create(fragment: FragmentActivity): CartItemViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(fragment).get(CartItemViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

The point here is that `CartItem` are being loaded, however how can I fill, in the proper way, `Item` and `Service` object?

If any another informaton is needed, please let me know.
Thanks.

Edit: Creating the Repository which makes `onChanged` don't be called anymore.

```
class CartItemRepository {

    companion object {

        fun getLiveData(): LiveData<List<CartItem>> {
            val liveData = MutableLiveData<List<CartItem>>()

            doAsync {
                val cartItems = MainApplication.getInstance().cartItemDao.all
                for (cartItem in cartItems) {
                    val item = MainApplication.getInstance().itemDao.get(cartItem.itemId)
                    cartItem.item = item
                    val service = MainApplication.getInstance().serviceDao.get(cartItem.serviceId)
                    cartItem.service = service
                }
                liveData.value = cartItems
            }

            return liveData
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than getting the `CartItem` directly from the DAO, get it from a repository, where the repository gets the "bare" `CartItem` from the DAO and fills in the `Item` and `Service`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, do you have any example of this repository?

Comment: Nothing very simple. The repository pattern is discussed briefly in [the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html). I have an extensive example with an RxJava2 repository (and a `ViewModel` with `LiveData` based on that repository) in [this book](https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch).

Comment: @DouglasFornaro is right. In the repository, you can fill both fields using LiveData Transformations https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html

Comment: I tried to create the Repository, the `onChanged` method wasn't being called anymore. See the update in above. What am I doing wrong?